# When querying storage at a particular block, are the values returned those before or after the execution of the extrinsics in that block?

Tags: storage, query

For example:
We have a storage item: `Counter` that is set to 0. An extrinsic `increment` in block 11 adds 1 to `Counter`.

If we query for the value of Counter at block 11, do we get 0 or 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It queries the state *after* execution of the block. So, 1.